How to make a trigger that deletes data from a table verify that the data that we pass it by the old. extension exists in a table
How to make that a trigger that deletes data of a table verifies that the data that we pass to it by the extension old. exists in a table on that is declared in the trigger.
I have the following trigger:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Clase_T_DeleteAlumno;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Clase_T_DeleteAlumno
BEFORE DELETE
ON Alumno FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE nombreHistorico VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE existe tinyint;
    DECLARE miError CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '43001';
    
    SET existe = (select count(*) from alumno where(dni = old.dni));
    
    if(existe = 0) then
        SIGNAL miError SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "ERROR. There is no DNI.";
    else
        DELETE FROM matriculado
        WHERE(dni = old.dni);
        SET nombreHistorico = (select nombre from alumno where(dni = old.dni));
        INSERT INTO alumno_historico VALUES (nombreHistorico, CURDATE());
    end if;
END;
//

NEW EDIT:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Clase_T_DeleteAlumno;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Clase_T_DeleteAlumno
BEFORE DELETE
ON Alumno FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE miError CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '43001';
    
    if(row_count() = 0) then
        begin
            SIGNAL miError SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "The DNI does not exist in the table Students";
        end;
    end if;
END;
//

This is my table. Alumno(dni(PK), nombre, edad)
I have created a variable that stores the result of a query by filtering the data passed by the extension old.[attribute]. This variable contains a value of 0 or 1. If the value is 0, it indicates that the data does not exist and throws the error, and if it is 1, it indicates the opposite. The deletion process only continues if the value is 1, that is, if the data exists in the table.
But when I try to do a deletion by passing it a DNI that does not exist, it does not finish verifying if it exists or not, it just continues with the event without throwing an error.
DELETE FROM alumno
WHERE(dni=4399);

In the student table I do not have any data in the DNI attribute like that and like others I have tried.
Any help would be great.

You seem to have an XY problem. Why are you deleting and inserting the same primary key? Such an operation is functionally equivalent to an update, so why not just execute an update?

A delete is only called if the record exists. Therefore, if you try to remove a DNI that does not exist, the trigger will not be called. However, if your goal is to save the deleted records, you can use an after trigger:
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Clase_T_DeleteAlumno;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Clase_T_DeleteAlumno
AFTER DELETE

ON Alumno FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE nombreHistorico VARCHAR(50);

    SET nombreHistorico = old.nombre;
    INSERT INTO alumno_historico VALUES (nombreHistorico, CURDATE());
        
END;
//

If you want to receive an error when there is no record to delete you can use a stored procedure:
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS delete_record;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_record(IN value_dni INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_count INT;
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) as tot INTO var_count
    FROM Alumno A
    WHERE A.dni = value_dni;
    
    IF var_count = 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "dmi does not exists";
    ELSE
        DELETE FROM alumno WHERE dni = value_dni;
    END IF;

    COMMIT;
END //

DELIMITER ;


So... Why is it that when I try to delete a DNI that does not exist in the Alumnos table, no error occurs?

When you attempt to delete a record from a table and that record doesn't exist, mysql doesn't throw an error. Instead, it executes the DELETE statement without affecting any rows.

No, I have tried to do the same thing by commenting out the part of the code that checks the DNI and creating the trigger again, and I have realized that when I pass it a DNI that does not exist it does not check the same thing, it just does it and that's it.

@MacREpiC are you saying that if you pass a DNI that does not exist it executes the DELETE statement without affecting any rows and without executes the trigger?

I am saying that by executing DELETE with a DNI that does not exist, it contradicts what you are telling me, which is that it throws an error, and it does not.

When I execute a DELETE with a DNI that does not exist mysql workbench does not throw an error, it says DELETE  FROM Alumno  WHERE (dni = 30) 0 row(s) affected 0.000 sec ;
PS (there is not a dni that is 30 in the table)

That is what I want to capture! If the number of affected rows is 0 it will throw an error.

@MacREpiC ok I got it, tell me if the new answer satisfies you.

I am not satisfied with your solution, sorry. I think I found the function that can help me solve the problem, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.
I have gone from doing previous checks of whether the DNI exists to putting at the end of the code (which is when it finishes deleting) a condition that checks that if the number of affected rows is 0 it means that the DNI does not exist, but this does not seem to be working. PS: I don't know how to send you another message with the updated code with the new condition.

Try to edit your answer adding the new code below your old one

Done, read "NEW EDIT".
